# reliable and platform-independent way of getting logged-in user in java

Tags: java, kerberos, jgss

We need a java application to run on both `solaris` and `windows machines` and they are `kerberized`. We use `JGSS` to get the Princiapl corresponding to the logged-in user in `Solaris`, by specifying the loction of credential cache that is stored in `KRB5CCNAME`. Since windows doesn't store the details in a file like `solaris` does, and since we don't want to use `NTSystem` to get the `logged-in user's name`, is there a generic way to get these details from a  `java program`? I see a lot of references mentioning about `JSSE` and `SSPI` to get these details.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function which returns informations similar to what you have asked. And for logged in user name, it is used as

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

Comment: The system property user.name is not **reliable** because one can run the class with `-Duser.name=abc` and the actual logged in user can be xyz.